# How many groups have at least 1 non-zero value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

I want to plot bar graph from the dataframe below.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['A','A','B','B','C','C'],
                    'X': [5,0,7,1,0,0],
                    'Y': [4,0,4,7,9,0],
                    'Z':[11,0,8,4,0,0]})


   URL  X   Y   Z
0   A   5   4   11
1   A   0   0   0
2   B   7   4   8
3   B   1   7   4
4   C   0   9   0
5   C   0   0   0
```

The `URL` counts should be on the y-axis, and `X`, `Y`, `Z` categories should be on the x-axis with two bars for each.

I have done the first bar (code at the end): it will show the number of non-zero values in each column.

### I need help with the second bar:

it should show how many (duplicate) `URL`s have at least 1 non-zero corresponding `X`, `Y` or `Z` value.

For example:

- `A` comes two times in the `URL`, and in the `X`-column we have one non-zero value - so it will count as 1.
- In the case of `B`: both values are non-zero, so we will count `B` as 1 as well.
- But in the case of `C`: since both values are 0 in `X` we will **not** count it as one.

The same goes for `Y` and `Z`.

---

I have managed to draw a bar graph for the first case, but for the second one I'm unable to:

```
(df2.melt("URL")
    .groupby("variable")
    .agg(Keywords_count = ("value", lambda x: sum(x != 0)),
         dup = ("URL", "nunique"))
    .plot(kind="bar") )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: When counting the number of values for the second bar - should we include the values where the `URL` has only 1 unique value (with non-zero `X`, of course)? Or do you want to consider _**only the duplicate**_ `URL`s?

Comment: In order to count the values for the second bar, these conditions should be fulfilled. If there are duplicates in `URL`, just count as one if there are non-zero values in the corresponding column X and the same goes for `Y` and `Z`. If there are no duplicates in `URL`, count them as well only if they have non-zero values in the corresponding column `X` and the same goes for `Y` and `Z`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) instead of [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html).

`.apply` can take the whole dataframe for each group (and thus can combine information from multiple columns), while `.agg` operates only on one column at a time.

```py
def f(df):
    n_non_zero_vals = (df["value"] != 0).sum()
    # # If only duplicated URLs should be considered:
    # df = df[df['URL'].duplicated(keep=False)]
    # # Alternative:
    # df = df.groupby("URL").filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
    n_urls = df.groupby("URL")["value"].agg("any").sum()
    return pd.Series([n_non_zero_vals, n_urls],
                     index=['Keywords_count', 'dup'])

(df2.melt("URL")
    .groupby("variable")
    .apply(f)
    .plot(kind="bar") )

plt.show()
```

[image]